# Help identifying mystery "KE" IC

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, identification, components

I'm trying to resurrect a computer board that was damaged by overvoltage, and I'm having trouble identifying one of the components.

It's a surface-mount chip, six pins, 2mm along its longest side, and the only identifying markings are the letters "KE".

From what I can tell by its position it is power related, either a transformer or a diode of some kind.  The board has a 5V supply voltage. All instances of this component I've found are labelled as "DC*n*".

[image: Close-up of chip, 6-pin "KE" IC highlighted with a red box]

I've written to the manufacturer asking for a circuit diagram or list of parts, but I haven't heard back. Does anyone on here happen to know what this chip is and where/if I can find a replacement? If it makes any difference, the board is a Diamond Systems AUR-Z530 series.

Comment: From the designator DC Likely a clamping diode array, such as a TVS.

It looks like just protecting the KBMS1 external header from ESD.

Likely not at all related to your motherboard being toast from overvoltage. Also no manufacturer will support a common user with motherboard schematics, that's business critical info, they won't bother even answering.

Comment: Looks like pins 2 and 5 are the power rail(s), and the other pins are the TVS pins.  Make sure none of them are shorted to the power rail(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually heard back from the manufacturers in the end; it is indeed a diode/TVS array, specifically a PLR0504F. I was linked to a datasheet here: http://www.protekdevices.com/xyz/documents/datasheets/plr0504f.pdf